# How to cast C# object to Java.lang object in Xamarin Android?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

```
Java.Util.Concurrent.PriorityBlockingQueue m_sensorDataQueue = new Java.Util.Concurrent.PriorityBlockingQueue();

m_sensorDataQueue.Add(c# to java object);
```

m_sensorDataQueue is java class i want to add c# object into this.

Comment: You would have to create a Java.Lang.Object-based class. But if you have C# class, why are you trying to use a Java-based queue?

Comment: Because I haven't found any PriorityBlockingQueue class in C# as well as I created class which extends Java.Lang.Object class.

Comment: What do you mean you did not find any `PriorityBlockingQueue` class in C#? Because i am pretty sure it is available in the following namespace `Java.Util.Concurrent.PriorityBlockingQueue`

Comment: There is no PriorityBlockingQueue in Xamarin.

Comment: Did you check in the `Java.Util.Concurrent` namespace?

Comment: Yes I have used it but to add object to this we have to pass Java object not C# object.

Comment: And what are you planning to add in there? I mean which C# object are you trying here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187854/discussion-between-ashish-kumawat-and-g-hakim).

Comment: If your C# object inherits from Java.Lang.Object, you should be fine. Or use Cheesebaron's idea in his answer (likely better approach)

Answer (score 1):

For those looking for the answer to the title: "How to cast C# object to Java.Lang.Object in Xamarin Android?", I was able to do this with a wrapper class. Not sure if it's the best way, but I'm able to store my C# object as a property of a Java.Lang.Object. I honestly don't know how reliable this is or memory efficient/thread-safe/etc, but my C# class is all informational: no methods, only properties of simple data types.

If you have access to the C# object class, and it's not already a class that is extending another class, and you don't care if there's java compiled in that code, you can make the C# class extend Java.Lang.Object:

```
public class MyCSharpObject : Java.Lang.Object
{
    public MyCSharpObject() { } //constuctor 
    ...
}
```

If that's not possible (you don't have access to the original class, or need to keep it a C# object for supporting other platforms like iOS) you can make a wrapper that extends Java.Lang.Object and uses the C# type as a property:

```
public class MyCSharpObjectJava : Java.Lang.Object
{
    public MyCSharpObject MyObject;
    public MyCSharpObjectJava(MyCSharpObject myObject)
    {
        MyObject = myObject;
    }
}
```

Create a new instance:

```
var jObj = new MyCSharpObjectJava(csObj);
```

Then to access the original class on the other end:

```
MyCSharpObject original = jObj.MyObject;
```

This is how I'm able to take my C# class object instance, assign it to a Java.Lang.Object wrapper and store it on a Google Maps Android Api marker as the Tag, and then on tapping the marker, able to convert it back to the original object.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for [ConcurrentQueue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentqueue-1?view=netframework-4.7.2) which you can find in the NuGet [System.Collections.Concurrent](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Collections.Concurrent/).

The usage would be like:

```
var queue = new ConcurrentQueue<TObject>();

// queue stuff
queue.Enqueue(myObject);
queue.Enqueue(myOtherObject);

// peek
queue.TryPeek(out var result);

// dequeue
queue.TryDequeue(out var result);
```

Where `TObject` is the type of your object.

Comment: TryDequeue() does not return removed object like Poll() in PriorityBlockingQueue

Comment: Yes, it does return the removed object as part of the `out` parameter. The method itself returns bool to indicate whether the operation went well.